# Excluir caracteres de uma string

Tags: c#

Olá, tenho o seguinte trecho de código: `agenciaModel.Bcx_Nome = agenciaViewModel.Bcx_Nome;` a `agenciaModel` é enviada para a `api` e enviada para o `banco de dados`, porém no banco de dados o tamanho máximo da string é 35, como posso excluir os caracteres excedentes a 35?

Caso não tenham entendido: eu tenho uma variável no meu projeto que não tem limite de caracteres, mas quando vou enviar para a api essa variável eu quero q envie apenas os 35 primeiro caracteres, para que não tenha erro ao inserir no bd, como eu excluo o resto dos caracteres da string(os caracteres excedentes a 35)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Substring`:

```
string resultado = texto.Substring(0, 35);
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado, quando der o tempo eu aceito a pergunta